# Is there a difference between array.sort(x => -1) and array.reverse()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reverse

I came accross `Array.sort` (with function parameter). When you return `-1` in the function, the array is reversed.

`Array.reverse` also does this. Is there a difference between those two functions?


Examples:

```js
var numbers = [3, 7, 1, 8, 3, 9];
numbers.sort(x => -1);
console.log(numbers);

var numbers = [3, 7, 1, 8, 3, 9];
numbers.reverse();
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: Yes, the first one is not guaranteed to work at all.

Comment: You know why? @VLAZ

Comment: With `x => -1`, you just indicate to the sort algorithm that every value is lower than every other value, basically making the return value meaningless. The result thus depends solely on the algorithm and implementation detail of `sort`, which is unknown/undefined/may change.

Comment: Returning only a single type of value from the comparator function will likely get in conflict with any optimisation. The algorithm is free to *avoid* comparing any two values. So if it checks `compare(a, c)` and `compare(a, b)` it can skip `compare(b, c)`.

Comment: Try with a longer array (that will typically use a different algorithm) and see it fail